# How send all cart items by using form and insert into the database table

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have some problems while placing order in my php shopping cart website. I added cart items successfully but when i placing order the all cart items need to insert my database order table. I am using form to post all values from cart and insert into database. There is last updated cart item only inserted my database. The remaining items did not insert into my database. Anybody please help me. Thanks in advance.

My code is

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {

    $item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from products WHERE pid='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $product_name = $row["pname"];
        $price = $row["price"];
        $details = $row["description"];
        $image = '<img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src = "admin123/products/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="50" height="50" border="1" />';
    }
    $pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
    $cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;

    $cartOutput .='  <form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column">'.$image.'
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column text">
                            <a href="store.php?pid='.$item_id.'">'.$product_name.'</a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column text">
                            <p>Price: '.$price.'&nbsp;€&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column quantity">
                            <div class="quantity buttons_added pm-checkout-quantity">
                                  <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty cart text" title="Qty" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" name="quantity" min="1" step="1" >                    
                            </div><!-- quantity buttons end -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column text">
                            <p>Sub-Total: '.$pricetotal.'&nbsp;€&nbsp;</p>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column">
                            <a href="cart.php?index_to_remove='.$i.'" class="pm-rounded-btn pm-primary pm-cart-remove">Remove</a>
                        </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="order-pname" value="'.$product_name.'">
<input type="hidden" name="order-price" value=" '.$price.'">
<input type="hidden" name="order-qty" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">
<input type="hidden" name="order-total" value="'.$pricetotal.'">
<input type="hidden" name="item-id" value="' . $item_id . '">

                         ';
                         $i++;
                         }
```

and i am closing my form tag in between my body tag.

And the insert code is below

```
if(isset($_POST['place-order']))
{
    $pid = $_POST['item-id'];
    $ocname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $oclname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $opname=$_POST['order-pname'];
    $oprice=$_POST['order-price'];
    $oqty=$_POST['order-qty'];
    $ototal=$_POST['order-total'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $address=$_SESSION['address']; 
    $city=$_SESSION['city'];
    $state=$_SESSION['state'];
    $country=$_SESSION['country'];
    $zip= $_SESSION['zip'];
    $phone=$_SESSION['phone'];
    $sql =mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (pid, customer_name, customer_lname, product_name, qty, price, total, date_added, customer_email, customer_address, customer_city, customer_state, customer_country, customer_zip, customer_phone ) VALUES('$pid','$ocname','$oclname', '$opname', '$oqty','$oprice','$ototal', now(), '$email','$address','$city','$state','$country','$zip','$phone' ) ") or die(mysql_error());

}
```

So anybody please help me.

Comment: as i understand your code i think problem is in your search query "$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from products WHERE pid='$item_id' LIMIT 1");" why you put limit here?? this query fetch only 1 item.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But there is no problem it select and displays all cart items but the items cant insert into my database table. That is the problem. Thank you

Comment: problem is that you are not using loop. although you are getting all records, you see you are using while loop to get all records but when you insert you are not using loop so the last product in your loop is added. so use loop as well in your insert query

Comment: Where can i add loop for this code. Can you please help me

Comment: i am sending you code example in answer

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you are inserting only single item, although you getting all records but you are not using loop so only the last product is inserted in your database so formate your code as follow!

```
foreach ($_SESSION["cart_array"] as $each_item) {

$item_id = $each_item['item_id'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * from products WHERE pid='$item_id' LIMIT 1");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
    $product_name = $row["pname"];
    $price = $row["price"];
    $details = $row["description"];
    $image = '<img style="border:#666 1px solid;" src = "admin123/products/' . $item_id . '.jpg" alt="' . $product_name. '" width="50" height="50" border="1" />';
}
$pricetotal = $price * $each_item['quantity'];
$cartTotal = $pricetotal + $cartTotal;

$cartOutput .='  <form action="cart.php" method="post">
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column">'.$image.'
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column text">
                        <a href="store.php?pid='.$item_id.'">'.$product_name.'</a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column text">
                        <p>Price: '.$price.'&nbsp;€&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column quantity">
                        <div class="quantity buttons_added pm-checkout-quantity">
                              <input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty cart text" title="Qty" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" name="quantity" min="1" step="1" >                    
                        </div><!-- quantity buttons end -->
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column text">
                        <p>Sub-Total: '.$pricetotal.'&nbsp;€&nbsp;</p>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 pm-cart-info-column">
                        <a href="cart.php?index_to_remove='.$i.'" class="pm-rounded-btn pm-primary pm-cart-remove">Remove</a>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="order-pname[]" value="'.$product_name.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="order-price[]" value=" '.$price.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="order-qty[]" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '">
                    <input type="hidden" name="order-total[]" value="'.$pricetotal.'">
                    <input type="hidden" name="item-id[]" value="' . $item_id . '">

                     ';
                     $i++;
                     }
```

your post and insert code must be as follow!

```
    if(isset($_POST['place-order']))
{    $allpid = $_POST['item-id'];
    $oqty=$_POST['order-qty'];
    $ototal=$_POST['order-total'];

    $opname=$_POST['order-pname'];
    $oprice=$_POST['order-price'];
    $i=0;
    foreach($allpid as $id)
    {
    $pid=$id;
    $ocname = $_SESSION['fname'];
    $oqty=$oqty[$i];
     $ototal=$ototal[$i];
     $opname=$opname[$i];
    $oprice=$oprice[$i];
    $oclname = $_SESSION['lname'];
    $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    $address=$_SESSION['address']; 
    $city=$_SESSION['city'];
    $state=$_SESSION['state'];
    $country=$_SESSION['country'];
    $zip= $_SESSION['zip'];
    $phone=$_SESSION['phone'];
    $sql =mysql_query("INSERT INTO orders (pid, customer_name, customer_lname, product_name, qty, price, total, date_added, customer_email, customer_address, customer_city, customer_state, customer_country, customer_zip, customer_phone ) VALUES('$pid','$ocname','$oclname', '$opname', '$oqty','$oprice','$ototal', now(), '$email','$address','$city','$state','$country','$zip','$phone' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
    $i=$i+1;
    }
}
```

This is my answer for you in the situation you given, but i suggest you to separate tables for customer data and product data.